# How to add whatsapp_business_management and whatsapp_business_messaging permission to your Facebook APP?

Tags: facebook, whatsapp-cloud-api

I have Facebook live application, i want to use with WhatsApp Cloud API. I have added whatsapp product to my app, connected it to BM account and expected to see permissions:

- whatsapp_business_management
- whatsapp_business_messaging

In the "Permissions and Features" section.

But there are no such permissions in this section.

__

On my another app, after adding whatsapp,  permissions are appeared. What can i do with the first app, what is wrong with it?

Comment: What is your app _type_ that you selected when creating it?

Comment: @CBroe Business type

Comment: Not sure if permissions are supposed to show up there just because you added the product, I think your app needs to _ask_ for the permissions at least once, before they will show up in the app review section?

Comment: Try creating an access token with the graph api tool with these two permission added, then a popup window will open and ask to grant access. After that, you should be able to see those permissions in "Permissions and Features" section